# jquery select statement to return

Tags: jquery, arrays, linq

I want to create a `jquery` `select` statement that will return `email` from an `array` of `users` that contain more than just `email` for each `user`.

```
var _userObject = linq.From($vw.listVwObservable().Users());
```

This statement returns an `Array[6]` each of the elements has a `viewModel` and within the `viewModel` is the Email that I want to extract.

How can I specify my `Linq` statement to `select` the email within the `viewmodel` for each of the elements of the `array`?

Comment: where is you jQuery code an returned array my friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var emails = $.map(
    linq.From($vw.listVwObservable().Users()),
    function(user){
        return user.email
    });
```